# How to design a Select statement with in line functions and single fields

Tags: sql, db2

I'm attempting to design a single SELECT statement that will do the following.

I'm creating a report that shows a file number, a statement value associated with the file number, a total invoice value that is built from all of the invoices associated with the file number, and then the difference between the statement and invoice values if there is one. finally it shows the payment due date.

The report is only suppose to show files where there is a difference between the total invoices and the value of the statement. It is also restricted by only invoices that are marked as Payable (not 'V'), by certain charge codes, and by not being 'FLAGGED' as being worked on.

The data is arranged into three tables. IMPSTATP is for the file level and contains the file number and statement value. The other two are the Invoice header and Invoice payable files.

Now obviously what I have below won't work, but I'm running into some difficulties visualizing a single select statement that will.

```
SELECT
    P.OFFIV, FILEST, TOTDST, PDUEST,
    sum(P.AMTPIV - P.DTDCIV),
    TOTDST - sum(AMTPIV - DTDCIV) 
FROM
    IMPSTATP
JOIN ACCIHEDP AS H ON FILEST = H.FILEIV and BKRST = H.BKRIV
JOIN ACCIPBLP AS P ON H.INVIV = P.INVIV and H.BKRIV = P.BKRIV and H.OFFIV = P.OFFIV
WHERE
    H.VDPDIV <> 'V' AND 
    (P.CHGPIV = '011' OR
    P.CHGPIV = '012' OR
    P.CHGPIV = '093') AND
    P.VNNMIV <> 'FLAGGED'
GROUP BY FILEST
HAVING
    TOTDST - sum(P.AMTPIV - P.DTDCIV) <> 0;
```

Keep in mind that this is with an old DB2 database on an IBM iSeries. Any and all suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Hi @joesph-oliff , welcome to SO or sort of ... I'm reading your question and I'll be honest with you: I don't know what are your premises (what your data look like) , what means your query and what kind of results you are expecting ... This is a very good article on how to ask a good question ... http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really sure how to fully explain what it is that i'm trying to do without going into a long explanation about accounting. Know what I mean? Will read the article and see if I can reword better.

Comment: Since you're checking that CHGPIV = '011' AND CHGPIV = '012' AND CHGPIV = '093', I don't expect that you'll see results from this query. As @Andy K points out, you'll need to reword your question a bit. Example data, expected output, table structures, what you've tried, and what specifically was wrong with the results that you got from your attempt(s) - error messages, the data was wrong, etc.

Comment: @joesph-olliff you'll have to. We spend time on your question , give us some props by spending time on how you are phrasing your question ;)

Comment: @AndyK I have edited for further clarity. I believe that it accurately portrays all relevant information. Let me know if there is any further data that is needed. Also I changed my mistake in the WHERE clause

Comment: You need to group invoices by file first, then join that result to `IMPSTATP`. I belive this gives you all relevant information.

Comment: @mustaccio Would you mind listing an answer or maybe a psuedo-code example? Thanks